# Percentage with NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have an input `NSString` and I want to get ouput with `%` at the end

I tried to do the following but it failed

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", self.tName.text ] );
```

where tName is `UITextfield`

the problem is at console if i typed A the output will be `A` not `A%`

Any suggestion to solve that?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're experiencing? (And what relevance does the console have?) Me confused.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using `NSLog()` correctly. `NSLog()` is meant to be called with a constant format string (`%@%%`, for instance), and be passed in arguments. What you're doing is parsing these arguments beforehand, and then passing the string you want to print to `NSLog()`, which doesn't work.

When you write `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", @"Hello!"]`, the string you get back is `@"Hello!%"`, which is what you want to print. However, when you pass it into `NSLog()`, it thinks that that is the format string it needs to parse, sees the single percent sign and doesn't know what to do (it expects getting something after the percent sign), so it ignores it. Essentially, what you're doing is this:

```
NSLog(@"Hello!%");
```

Try it out and you'll see it won't work. Using a correct `NSLog()` call will fix your problem:

```
NSLog(@"%@%%", self.tName.text);
```

Read up on `NSLog()` and its variable counterpart, `NSLogv()` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: it's not passed to another nsstring I mean @"Hello!%" not be passed  I used nslog to just testing

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear (I've updated my answer to make it more obvious). You're creating the string to be printed using `NSString` when you shouldn't be. It creates a string like `@"A%"` which `NSLog()` then tries to parse and can't. Just call `NSLog(@"%@%%", self.tName.text);` and it'll work.

Comment: the output   When you write [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", @"Hello!"], the string you get back is @"Hello!" instead of @"Hello!%" , that is my problem which I want to fix

Comment: Ali, you're definitely doing something wrong. How are you printing that string? And what output do you get when you try `NSLog(@"%@%%", @"Hello!");`? Please be clear.

Comment: forget teh nslog , I need using nstringwithformate to get @"hello!%"

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", @"Hello!"]` will definitely do that for you. However, my concern is that you don't realize that that's what it returns because you're trying to log it with `NSLog()` which isn't working for you because it prints `@"Hello!"`. Try this: `fputs([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", @"Hello!"] UTF8String], stdout);`, and let me know what it prints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but simply using `%%` will output the percentage sign, as per the String Format Specifiers section of the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

Comment: I think its because they tried to construct the code inside a NSlog to test the output, before they wrote the actual code and then checked its output with a NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

I just have tested your case like the following:

```
NSString *s = @"100";
NSLog(@"%@%%",s);
```

the Output was: 100%

try this would it make a difference?

```
 NSLog(@"%@%%",self.tName.text);
```